# Hydration error when using Local Storage in Next.js v13.2.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js13, hydration

I get this error when using nextjs in local storage whenever the page reloads in Next 13

Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML. Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "" Client: "0"

```
let cartFromLocalStorage;
let total_quant_from_lc;

if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
    cartFromLocalStorage =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart") || "[]" )
    total_quant_from_lc =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("total_quant") || "0")

 }

    const [cartItems, setcartItems] = useState(cartFromLocalStorage);
    const [totalQuantities, settotalQuantities] = useState(total_quant_from_lc);
 
useEffect(() => {

  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartItems)  )
  localStorage.setItem("total_quant",  JSON.stringify(totalQuantities) )

}, [cartItems, totalQuantities])
```

For some reason, the server side is rendering when I have no use of it whatsoever in my application. There is always a mismatch of total quantities on the server side being "" while on the client side, totalquantities is set to whatever value "total_quant" is in the local storage. Basically, the client side rendering is giving me issues. Any help?

Error code
[image: Error code here]

Comment: Can you show the component as a hole to have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?